# Using Fetch in a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, fetch

I'm currently using php and javascript in my Wordpress plugin. The idea is that javascript `fetch` updates the database. Currently I have a page with "server" shortcode and I fetch this page from the "client" page. This server page receives the fetched data (POST request) and does some database updating and returns a new value in a small XML data patch (added via shortcode).

The system works, but I'd want to improve it. Preferably, so that the "server" fetch would not return the entire page (headers, footers, css and all), but only the data file (i.e. `application/xml` instead of `text/html`).

Can I accomplish this while still maintaining my access to `global $wpdb` and other features of Wordpress? I tried another way: I managed to expose a php file by adding it to `pluginpath/includes`, but I am unable to use `$wpdb` there, which is how I access my database.

So, requested help, either, or: (a) how do I enable use of $wpdb in the small php "server file" (that does database fiddling) or (b) how do I make the Wordpress page suppress all other data than the data patch (small XML) that I want to pass?

Aimed result: as few bytes as possible moving in the internet. (So, bytes instead of kilobytes.)

**Edit** Amending my question (after initial help from Mark Truitt): I have enabled wordpress ajax stuff and it's working when I do `jQuery.ajax( { ...} )`.

Question: Is it possible to get this working with `fetch`? I.e. `fetch( ajaxurl, {...} ).then( .... )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/

Since you are using JS anyway you could pass what you need to the endpoint then return specifically what you need. Without knowing more of what you are trying to get. You could specifically request it back as json etc.

Comment: Thank you, I had a look into this and it seems I am starting to understand it. (I saw this wp_ajax mentioned here and there, but was unable to understand before...)

Comment: It is a bit weird at first but when it clicks, it makes life for some things 10x easier.

Comment: Thank you. I finally understood it and managed to get the system working. Thank you for your help! Do you know if `fetch` can reach these ajax queries or do I have to use jquery.ajax?

Comment: Honestly not sure, I tend to stick with what is baked in if it fits though a quick glance at the docs and some Googling you should be able to make it work though not sure it would be worth the effort if you already have it working as Fetch looks to be more of a replacement for XMLHttpRequest.